# How to use Apache AyncHttpClient to send chunked requests

Tags: httprequest, apache-httpclient-4.x, chunked

I want to have a send a request body generating the body a piece at a time, but without knowing the entire length ahead of time. In other words, I need to send a chunked request.

I can't find how to do this.

> The main distinction between two types of connections is inability to use the usual, but inherently blocking `java.io.InputStream` and `java.io.OutputStream` classes to represent streams of inbound and outbound content. HttpCore NIO provides `ContentEncoder` and `ContentDecoder` interfaces to handle the process of asynchronous content transfer.
>
> ...
>
> Non-blocking HTTP connections will fire output events until the content entity is marked as fully transferred.
>
> ```
> ContentEncoder encoder = <...>
> // Prepare output data
> ByteBuffer src = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);
> // Write data out
> encoder.write(src);
> // Mark content entity as fully transferred when done
> encoder.complete();
> ```

I looked at `org.apache.http.nio.conn.ClientAsyncConnection`, but I can't see where the output events are being fired.

I can find examples for sending files, but none for the content generation that I want to do.

How do I send a streaming, chunked request with the `AsyncHttpClient`?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom `HttpAsyncRequestProducer` and make it stream out content either using one of the provided `HttpAsyncContentProducer` or implement your own content generation logic

```
public class MyAsyncRequestProducer implements HttpAsyncRequestProducer {

    private final HttpHost target;
    private final HttpAsyncContentProducer producer;

    public MyAsyncRequestProducer(
            final HttpHost target,
            final HttpAsyncContentProducer producer) {
        super();
        Args.notNull(target, "HTTP host");
        Args.notNull(producer, "HTTP content producer");
        this.target = target;
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    public synchronized HttpRequest generateRequest() {
        BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest request = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest("POST", "/");
        BasicHttpEntity entity = new BasicHttpEntity();
        entity.setContentType(ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN.toString());
        entity.setContentLength(-1);
        entity.setChunked(true);
        request.setEntity(entity);
        return request;
    }

    public HttpHost getTarget() {
        return this.target;
    }

    public synchronized void produceContent(
            final ContentEncoder encoder, final IOControl ioctrl) throws IOException {
        this.producer.produceContent(encoder, ioctrl);
        if (encoder.isCompleted()) {
            this.producer.close();
        }
    }

    public void requestCompleted(final HttpContext context) {
    }

    public void failed(final Exception ex) {
    }

    public synchronized boolean isRepeatable() {
        return this.producer.isRepeatable();
    }

    public synchronized void resetRequest() throws IOException {
        this.producer.close();
    }

    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        this.producer.close();
    }

}
```